# How to get value for check boxes with same name from POST request using Node?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in Node lang. I am trying to get checkbox 'hobbies[]' values from req.body object but I am not able to do this.
Below is `req.body` value:

```
{ title: 'Ume',
  gender: 'female',
  'hobbies[]': [ 'cricket', 'read', 'tv' ],
  details: 'wQEqeQE' 
}
```

And HTML:

```
  <input type="checkbox" value ="cricket" class="form-control" name="hobbies[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value ="read" class="form-control" name="hobbies[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value ="tv" class="form-control" name="hobbies[]">
```

Comment: I am not sure about server package but i am using express handlebars and body-parser

Comment: That's Great Idea @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  It worked. Thanks .You saved my time :)

Comment: name="hobbies" worked to get values

Comment: From your `req.body` object, it appears as though you're getting the values, in the `hobbies[]` property... what's the problem?

Comment: turned into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using PHP's syntax for capturing a group of values in an array, which doesn't apply to other server packages in other languages.

Since you're using express, with express body-parser, just use `name="hobbies"` and you should get the result you want without the "syntax" becoming part of the property name in the resulting object.